# Reversing ArrayFormula Results

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have an ArrayFormula which is taking a list of dates and times in text format from Col A, and creating true dates/times in Col B:

```
=arrayformula( 
  regexreplace(A2:A, "^([\w, ]+) at ([\w: ]+)$", "$1 $2") 
)
```

Trying to figure out how to reverse the order of the results, so the most recent date is at the top of the list, but maxing out my formula knowledge and not finding anything as I Google around.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Drew, your intent isn't quite clear. Do you want the results sorted with the most recent data/time at the top with the furthest-back date/time at the bottom? Or do you want the list sorted in reverse order of entry in Column A, regardless of date/time order? (Or are these the same thing in your sheet, i.e., every row's date/time is later than the row before it?) It would be a lot easier to receive help if you shared a link to a sample spreadsheet including, say, 10 pieces of realistic data in Column A, with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result